# jQuery Active State Navigation using URLs Sub-String

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I've setup a jQuery navigation with active state. Now I would like to modify the code so it uses a Sub-String of the URL to execute the active state. I would like to have the script detecting only the numbers that are after "%5E" in the URL since ALL my URLs are the exact same and the only thing that differ is the numbers that are after "%5E". Thanks All!

```
  $(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/)[1];
    var target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
    $(target).addClass('active');
  }); 

<ul id="menu">
  <li id="Div1"><a href="/cat/1267-sale.aspx/1/80000000%5E1269">All</a></li>
  <li id="Div2"><a href="/cat/1267-sale.aspx/1/80000000%5E1266">Div1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think '^' is not safe to use in URLs. http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/ Check this article.

Comment: @Shanoop Thanks, I've updated my original code to have ^ encoded to %5E. Now it's all right. Please help if you can contribute to my question solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be...

```
var page = pathname.match(/\^(\d+)$/)[1];
```

And definitely reconsider using `^` in your URLs, as Shanoop suggested.

**--- Update ---**

Updated regex based on new URL pattern posted by OP...

```
var pathname = "/cat/1267-sale.aspx/1/80000000%5E1269";
var match = pathname.match(/[%5E|^](\d+)$/);
var page = match ? match[1] : null;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49s7F/2/

Comment: this is the error I got : TypeError: pathname.match(...) is null

Comment: Did you change the regex to match your new URL pattern?

Comment: Your code works great if using %5E in My URLs! The problem I'm having is even if I write my URL using the %5E my application turn it back to with ^. So can you edit that JsFiddle code so it uses the ^ instead of %5E. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated to match either `^` or `%5E`

Comment: Hello Anthony :) The code works really well, one last question, what about if I want to still use the code to detect normal urls that don't have the "/1/80000000%5E1269" and only : /cat/1267-sale.aspx

Comment: This will also detect the `1234` in `/1234-xxxxx.aspx` at the end of the URL... `var match = pathname.match(/[%5E|^|\/](\d+)($|-[^\/]+$)/);`

Comment: Thanks Anthony but the other pages have the same 1234 in their URLs, this makes all the tabs active.